# how to correctly build an app for device and simulator that conditionally uses the correct framework. (not a universal/fat framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, carthage

Have obtained separate frameworks for device and simulator, and I want to integrate those frameworks to achieve the desired functionality.
I have included the simulator framework in my carthage framework project. When I am compiling my framework, I am getting the following error

building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"OBJCCLASS$...", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
"OBJCCLASS$...", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in DepedencyInjector.o
objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

reference:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/66978
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/66978?answerId=215100022#215100022

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option for you to link both of the frameworks together you can just let the compiler decide. In this case you create a FAT binary. This means:

- you link both frameworks together
- create one (FAT) framework
- link this library to your app in Xcode
- let the compiler decide about the correct architecture

The command to create a FAT binary is:

```
lipo -create ./Simulator.framework/framework_binary ./Device.framework/framework_binary -output ./Universal
```

Now you have to duplicate the folder `Device.framework` and name it `Universal.framework`.

Copy the binary created with lipo into this folder.

Then open the file `./Universal.framework/Info.plist` and add the string  `iPhoneSimulator` in the `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` array.

Now copy `x86_64.swiftdoc` and `x86_64.swiftmodule` from the folder `Simulator.framework/Modules/framework_name.swiftmodule/` and paste them to
`Universal.framework/Modules/framework_name.swiftmodule/`.

Import the created universal framework into Xcode in your targets `Embedded Binries` section and you should be able to compiler your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a XCFramework as follows (from the command line).

```
xcodebuild \
    -create-xcframework \
    -framework  "<<path to simulator xcarchive>>/Products/Library/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework" \
    -framework  "<<path to device xcarchive>>/Products/Library/Frameworks/SomeFramework.framework" \
    -output     "CombinedFramework.xcframework"
```

You can add more to this and set the various paths and output to taste.

Not sure if this helps as you are not looking for universal frameworks and not sure how you classify this one ...

Comment: this command is giving the following error: 
unable to read the file at '/Users/pravir.ahuja/Desktop/frameworkFolder/iOSSDK-device.framework /iOSSDK-device'

Comment: Also, I don't have access to the code repo from which those frameworks were developed. I just have the .framework files for device and simulator

Comment: Check that path - I think you have a space after framework. Check the paths again if you get an error. This is typical approach to build framework for both device and simulator, but is also a universal framework. There are some good answers that take you through the whole process on SO and elsewhere but then typically you have the source. I don't think it matters if you do not have the source as the command I give just combines the compiled frameworks into a single framework.