# How to import (and use) Objective-C XCFramework inside a Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Let's say that I have an `Objective-C compiled XCFramework` called **A.XCFramework**, and a Swift Framework developed by me conventionally called **B**.

I would like to import A.XCFramework inside my B target, and use its functions privately.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588555/how-to-correctly-build-an-app-for-device-and-simulator-that-conditionally-uses-t/65597645#65597645

Comment: That’s not what I need. I’ve already got the compiled xcframework, I have to import the objective c one inside the swift framework!

Comment: You also need a header file on the Objective-C framework side, full of `#import <framework/somefile.h>` statements for all the headers you want to expose to Swift. Then on Swift side you pretty much just include the framework. Also, whenever you recompile the framework, I've noted, you need to exit Xcode or clear the Xcode derived data cache.